# Databricks Cluster Runs Notebook before all Libraries are started

Tags: databricks

I have a Notebook with some imports. I run my Notebook and received an `python module not found`  error.

When switching to the library section of the cluster, I saw that not all libraries were installed which caused the error.

[image]

How can I prevent that databricks runs Notebooks before all libraries are installed?

Comment: While this has not happened recently, this is known to have happened. In such a case, ensure that the library is mentioned as dependent in workflow task (avoid installing in cluster also to prevent duplicate installation) - In your notebook you can check if the library is available and sleep till it is available.